# Best form for asking places destination and vehicle type

Tags: forms, android, material-design

I am creating a layout that will ask user enter destination(google places address), vehicle type, price offering and an optional message.

[image: Layout page]

Is there any best way of making it simple for bike/car riders.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do the following:

1. Either go with [radio buttons](https://material.google.com/components/selection-controls.html#selection-controls-radio-button) or a [segmented control](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/UIKitUICatalog/UISegmentedControl.html) to really show that this is a multiple choice - single answer question. Of course you can style them so they look [something like this](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.4/checkboxradio-radio/#Horizontalgroup).
2. Put the labels for the icons (BIKE and CAR) below the icons, but inside the circle (or whatever you end up using).
3. Increase the font size and change the position of "Select Vehicle Type" since it looks too small/not connected to the choices (see: [principles of grouping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principles_of_grouping)).
4. I would find out the best default value and select this already. So if more than 50% are using a car then select that (and consider putting it left to the bike option). This way the majority of your users will save a tap/click, while the minority only has to do one tap (these users have to tap once anyway even with the old design).

I also think your text fields are still a little off (and the LATER button is placed slightly lower than the RIDE button). If I were you, I'd simply copy the material design guidelines to the teeth as they really help to get these "basics" down easily.

- For text input: https://material.google.com/components/text-fields.html
- For the search field: https://material.google.com/patterns/search.html#search-in-app-search
- For buttons: https://material.google.com/components/buttons.html#buttons-button-types

I'm just linking these since you're building a mobile service and I think it's way easier to follow these guidelines than to do it yourself (and the result will in 99% of the cases be better too).